# How to get lambda expression from Java Method

Tags: java, reflection, lambda

Suppose that I have the following method:

```
void test () {...}
```

I am getting this method via reflection, but invoking it will be very slow, so I want to get Runnable from it as if I will write

```
this::test
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post the code you have, for context.

Comment: If `Runnable r = this::test;` is not what you're looking for, then you should explain in more detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need an implementation for method like this: `Runnable toRunnable(Method method);` So we are getting a `Method` and we need to return `Runnable`

This is not exactly equivalent to `this::test`, since that also uses the `this` instance to bind to, so you will also have to pass an instance to bind to. But then you can use method handles, which is the underlying implementation for something like `this::test`.

With a class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void test() { 
        System.out.println("Test Called");
    }
}
```

You can create this method:

```
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.*;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.*;

...

public static Runnable toRunnable(Method method, Object instance) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Lookup lookup = lookup();

    MethodHandle test = lookup.unreflect(method);       
    try {
        return (Runnable) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            lookup,
            "run",
            methodType(Runnable.class, instance.getClass()),
            methodType(void.class),
            test,
            methodType(void.class)
        ).getTarget().invoke(instance);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Should not occur", e);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Object ref = new MyClass(); // get from somewhere

Runnable result = toRunnable(ref.getClass().getMethod("test"), ref);
result.run(); // prints 'Test Called'
```

The caveat is that the `test` method has to be accessible from the point at which you're calling `lookup()`, you can get around this either by passing the `Lookup` to the method manually, and creating it at a place where you can access the `test` method. Or if you're in Java 9 you can use `privateLookup(Class<?>, Lookup)` instead, but the `Lookup` you pass to that needs to be created in the same module as the method you're trying to access. (in short, method handles has a few more access restrictions to it). But if the method and class you're trying to access are publicly accessible then there's no problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that was exactly what I needed :)